# Animating instances in flash pro

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, adobe

So I have a game which consists of 3 frames, a start, rules, and actual game frame.

I would like to have an image of a face going from a neutral expression to a frowning face, while constantly moving it down.
I know to move it down you can do

```
instancename.y += 10;
```

But while it's going down, how would I make it so that every once in a while it frowns?

I have already drawn the multiple faces of the expression, so what would I need to have it frown?

I have photoshop if that makes much of a difference,

Comment: Do you want the frown face to happen randomly? Or at a constant time

Comment: I'd prefer random, but if the code/ what I need to do for set time is a lot shorter and easier, then I guess I'll do set time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure how often you want the frown face to run. It can be at a random time, or perhaps after certain distance, or you can set this up with a `Timer` to run at a specified interval. So I'll explain all 3.

First the random time. You'll need to do an import `flash.utils.getTimer` for this solution. I'm assuming you want you frowning face to stay a frowning face for more than 1ms. If that's the case then here's what I would do:

Set this member variable:

```
private var beginTime:Number;
```

Then before you run your first movement function:

```
beginTime = getTimer();
```

In your loop or movement function containing the `instancename.y` += 10;

```
private function loop():void {
    instancename.y += 10;

    //get our delta time        
    var dt:Number = getTimer() - beginTime; 
    //set random variable 50% chance to change the frame    
    var random:int = Math.random() * 2;

    //dt > 3000 just means 3 seconds have passed, you can lower that number to decrease the delay before we change frames for the "face" animation
    if ( random > 0 && dt > 3000 ) {
        beginTime = getTimer();

        if ( instancename.currentFrameLabel == "neutral" ) {
            instancename.gotoAndPlay("frowning");
        } 
        else {
            instancename.gotoAndStop("neutral");
        }
    }
}
```

This will change frames at a random time for a delay of 3000ms or 3 seconds (feel free to change that).

Now the distance version. So this is basically just saying when we reach a certain distance from some origin, change the frame. BUT this is reliant on an a couple variables being set:

```
//set the variable origin and a maxDistance
private var origin:Point = new Point( instancename.x, instancename.y );
private var maxDistance:int = 50;

//then in your loop or movement function
private function loop():void {
    instancename.y += 10;

    //when our distance is >= to our maxDistance, change the frame
    if ( Point.distance( new Point( spr.x, spr.y ), origin ) >= maxDistance ) {
        if ( instancename.currentFrameLabel == "neutral" ) {
            instancename.gotoAndPlay("frowning");
        } 
        else {
            instancename.gotoAndStop("neutral");
        }
        //set the origin variable again
        origin = new Point( instancename.x, instancename.y );
    }
```

And lastly the timer functionality. Set a timer variable with event listener of `TimerEvent.TIMER` and a function to call:

```
private var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 0);
```

Then set this where applicable:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, changeFrame);
timer.start(); //to start your timer
```

Then in the timer function:

```
private function changeFrame( e:TimerEvent ):void {
    if ( instancename.currentFrameLabel == "neutral" ) {
        instancename.gotoAndPlay("frowning");
    } 
    else {
        instancename.gotoAndStop("neutral");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to stop it when you're done using it: `timer.stop()`;

Those are several solutions to the problem. I should note that the second solution (the distance one) can be optimized a multitude of different ways, this was just one way of doing it.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but Ill be having tons and tons of these? Is there any way to edit the symbol/ instance itself to have it cycle through multiple frames?

Comment: Why don't you just use gotoAndPlay?

Comment: I've never heard of that? Can you give me a quick explanation?

Comment: Livedocs are your best friend : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay()

Comment: Also I updated the random version with a small change, realized I had copy/pasted a mistake, `dt = getTimer()` should have been `beginTime = getTimer()`

Comment: Ah thanks. Also about the gotoAndPlay: This works for frames, and I only have three frames. In my game, how would I have a frame running AND an instance/ symbol cycling through it's animation?